# Open a CMD command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to open a use this command from batch in a powershell script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -kiosk http://praxistipps.chip.de/ --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --window-position=0,0
```

So I tried this but with no success:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe"  -ArgumentList "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -kiosk http://praxistipps.chip.de/ --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --window-position=0,0
```

Comment: If you really want to start `chrome` via `cmd` (for whatever reason), you need to add `/C` as its first argument…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not call chrome directly?

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "-kiosk", "http://praxistipps.chip.de/", "--overscroll-history-navigation=0", "--window-position=0,0"
```

Comment: Oh yeah of cource... What a stupid mistake, thanks xD

Comment: @Forestbird It's a common mistake, you'd be surprised.